# exception thrown while processing service call

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing a rosservice call to a trigger camera exposure rate of a basler pylon camera... and I set the exposure rate to 50,000 or more each time... and I keep getting an exception saying:

"Exception thrown while processing servic ecall: Value 10.0000 must be greater than or equal 47.0000: OutOfRangeException thrown in node 'ExposureTimeAbs' while calling 'ExposureTimeAbs.SetValue( )'". 50,000 is way larger than 10.0000 so i don't understand why I get the error. but if i put in anything less than 47.0000, 45 for example, then the error reads 'Value 45.0000 must be greater than or equal 47.0000'. In my own created node, there is no comparison to 47 at all that I can see, and I cant seem to find that in the pylon camera code either.

anyone had this problem before or have any ideas why it is happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213854/exception-thrown-while-processing-service-call/) by [thailor3](https://answers.ros.org/users/22915/thailor3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-16**:
Could you give a bit more details? What driver are you using? What ROS version?

One thing I notice, but maybe it is just a formating issue:
You say, you call with `50,000` but it must be bigger than `10.0000`. Are you sure you are in the correct order of magnitued? So you don't mix comma with dots?

**Comment by [thailor3](https://answers.ros.org/users/22915/thailor3/) on 2015-07-17**:
Yes, the magnitude I have written here is correct. Fifty thousand vs ten point zero. It is ROS indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This actually looks as if you were only putting `10.0000` into the service call.
Can you check that there is actually `50000` in there? And don't write it with a comma...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1